# Configuring cross-compiler to use custom library search path

Tags: c, gcc, arm

I created a cross-toolchain for ARM (Raspberry Pi, to be specific). It's library search order is as follows:

```
armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi-gcc -print-search-dirs | grep libraries | sed "s/:/\n/g"

libraries
 =/usr/lib/gcc/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/
/usr/lib/gcc/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/lib/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/
/usr/lib/gcc/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/../../../../armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/lib/
/usr/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/lib/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/
/usr/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/lib/
/usr/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/
/usr/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/
```

And I would like to add

```
/usr/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/usr/local/lib/
```

to it.
As far as I know, cross-compilers ignore LIBRARY_PATH and have fixed search order.
But - is there any possibility to alter this search order at build time - i.e. when creating cross-toolchain? Maybe some ./configure options for gcc, or environment variables then?

I have seen some cross-toolchain, which had non-standard (but still fixed) library search order. Were they specified by ./configure options or similar mechanism, or was gcc hacked to achieve this?

Comment: Did you try passing -L<path> to gcc?

Comment: @longstar: Did you ever figure out how to specify the library search path when configuring and building gcc/g++? And ditto for specifying the desired header file search path when configuring and building gcc/g++.

Answer (score 1):

gcc takes a -L option which can specify the library path.

If your code has a makefile there is often a line in there you can add user-paths to.